# iMac running Windows 7 - can't turn off screen

Tags: windows-7, mac

I've just installed Windows 7 on a new iMac for a user who needs to run windows on it.  All seems fine except we can't work out how to turn the screen off without shutting down the whole machine.

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Closest you'll get is dropping the brightness down until the display goes black.  Probably a different story if you had it connected to an external display

Comment: Man, I was hoping it could be turned off but it really does seem it can't.  I've dropped the power settings to kill the display a little quicker which will have to do i guess.